# GNU make Not Deleting Intermediate Files

Tags: makefile

My makefile is as follows:

```
# The names of targets that can be built.  Used in the list of valid targets when no target is specified, and when building all targets.
TARGETS := libAurora.a libAurora.so

# The place to put the finished binaries.
TARGET_DIRECTORY := ./Binaries

# The compiler to use to compile the source code into object files.
COMPILER := g++

# Used when compiling source files into object files.
COMPILER_OPTIONS := -I. -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -g -O4

# The archiver to use to consolidate the object files into one library.
ARCHIVER := ar

# Options to be passed to the archiver.
ARCHIVER_OPTIONS := -r -c -s

SOURCE_FILES := $(shell find Source -type f -name *.cpp)
OBJECT_FILES := $(SOURCE_FILES:.cpp=.o)

.PHONY: Default # The default target, which gives instructions, can be called regardless of whether or not files need to be updated.
.INTERMEDIATE: $(OBJECT_FILES) # Specifying the object files as intermediates deletes them automatically after the build process.

Default:
    @echo "Please specify a target, or use \"All\" to build all targets.  Valid targets:"
    @echo "$(TARGETS)"

All: $(TARGETS)

lib%.a: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(ARCHIVER) $(ARCHIVER_OPTIONS) $(TARGET_DIRECTORY)/$@ $(OBJECT_FILES)

lib%.so: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(ARCHIVER) $(ARCHIVER_OPTIONS) $(TARGET_DIRECTORY)/$@ $(OBJECT_FILES)  

%.o:
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_OPTIONS) -c -o $@ $*.cpp
```

As you can see, the `.o` files are specified as intermediates via the `.INTERMEDIATE` target.  However, they are not deleted as expected after compilation finishes.  Instead, they remain where they were created, cluttering up my source directory.

The strange thing is that it works perfectly on another machine.  This leads me to believe it's a different version of `make`, but `man make` still shows it as the "GNU make utility."

Why won't `make` delete the intermediate files?

EDIT: `make -v` reports version 3.81.

EDIT: After manually deleting the `.o` files (i.e., a clean slate), `make All` produces the following output:

```
g++ -I. -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -g -O4 -c -o Source/File/File.o Source/File/File.cpp
g++ -I. -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -g -O4 -c -o Source/Timer/Timer.o Source/Timer/Timer.cpp
ar -r -c -s ./Binaries/libAurora.a Source/File/File.o Source/Timer/Timer.o
ar -r -c -s ./Binaries/libAurora.so Source/File/File.o Source/Timer/Timer.o
```

Comment: Do you really want to rebuild all your sources each time you make a change? If it's just the `.o` noise that's bothering you, just build them somewhere else. And use `make -v` to get the version.

Comment: @Mat If there's a better way that doesn't involve explicitly specifying each individual source file, do tell.

Comment: What does `make All` output when you run it?

Comment: Also, what OSes do your different machines run.  `make` has some different behaviors on Windows and Linux, I think.

Comment: Which version of Make is on the other machine?

Comment: Could it be because your rule for making object files has no prerequisites? You might try either (a) changing the rule to read `%.o: %.c` or (b) deleting the rule entirely and changing your variable names so that make can use the built-in rules to build objects (i.e., `$(COMPILER)` to `$(CXX)`, `$(COMPILER_OPTIONS)` to `$(CXXFLAGS)`). See the [list of variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) used by implicit rules in the GNU make manual. If either of those works I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Dan @Beta The other version of `make` I used was on my school computer, which ran OS X.  Unfortunately, I won't have access to that machine for quite some time now, so I can't get specific information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I copied this onto my machine and managed to reproduce both your problem and the solution.

Notice that in your `.INTERMEDIATE` target, you use `$(OBJECT_FILES)` as a prerequisite, but for the rule that makes `.o` files you use a pattern rule. This confuses `make` and it doesn't recognize that the both refer to the same thing.  There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Change the prerequisites of `.INTERMEDIATE` from `$(OBJECT_FILES)` to `%.o`, so it looks like

   ```
   .INTERMEDIATE: %.o
   ```
2. Change the rule for making .o files to

   ```
   $(OBJECT_FILES): $(SOURCE_FILES)
       $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_OPTIONS) -c $< -o $@
   ```

   or something like it.

I recommend the first solution, as it's less likely to cause weird problems with compilation if you have several source files.

More info on the intermediate target can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure, that the files are not there before you start building the project. The doc says clearly:

Therefore, an intermediate file which **did not exist before** `make` also **does not exist after** `make`.

If this is not the problem, you should post some debug output from make.

Comment: The problem persists after building from a clean slate.  I've posted output from `make All`.

Comment: Thanks @Maxpm, but for *debug output* use a `make -d All`, again from a clean state and post the output