# Why is make not deleting intermediate files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm having problems with GNU make 3.81 not deleting intermediate files. The issue is similar to [GNU make Not Deleting Intermediate Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512914/gnu-make-not-deleting-intermediate-files), but that answer doesn't solve my problem. I've distilled the issue to this test case:

```
default: 
    @echo no $@ target; exit 1

oncetwice: once twice
    @echo $@: $^

## Uncommenting the following line is sufficient to cause GNU make 3.81 to
## not delete the intermediate 'twice.dep', even if it didn't exist
## previously (i.e., was created by this invocation).
#another: twice.dep

%: %.dep
    @echo $^ >$@

## the following .INTERMEDIATE has no effect re: the twice: twice.dep
## dependency
.INTERMEDIATE: %.dep
%.dep:
    @echo $@ >$@
```

N.B. command blocks must be tab-indented.

That is, the target `once` depends on `once.dep` and `twice` depends on `twice.dep`. In addition, `another` also depends on `twice.dep`. It is this line that causes `twice.dep` to never be removed, even if make created it and despite the .INTERMEDIATE line.

The Makefile as posted gives:

```
snafu$ rm -f once* twice*; make oncetwice
oncetwice: once twice
rm once.dep twice.dep
```

Uncommenting the `twice: twice.dep` line:

```
snafu$ rm -f once* twice*; make oncetwice
oncetwice: once twice
rm once.dep
```

Notice that twice.dep is not rm'd in the second invocation.

From the info pages:

```
.INTERMEDIATE
The targets which .INTERMEDIATE depends on are treated as intermediate files.

[...]

Intermediate files are remade using their rules just like all other
files. But intermediate files are treated differently in two ways.

The first difference [...]

**The second difference is that if make does create b in order to update
something else, it deletes b later on after it is no longer
needed. Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make
also does not exist after make.**
```

I've tried making `another: twice.dep` a real rule with a command block. I've also tried variations of specifying .INTERMEDIATE as a pattern, a literal filename, and both. I've also tried using .PHONY.  make-3.82 NEWS doesn't appear to have any relevant fixes.  The behavior I'm witnessing looks more like that described for .SECONDARY targets.

Thanks,

Reece

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a pattern as a prerequisite of the .INTERMEDIATE special target (if you could, it would be documented in the manual; if the manual doesn't say you can, then you can't).

Further, GNU make 3.81 had a bug in it where .INTERMEDIATE wasn't working properly; this bug is fixed in 3.82.  If you change your file to use:

```
.INTERMEDIATE: twice.dep
```

(edit: original reply said "two.dep")

rather than "%.dep" and you switch to GNU make 3.82, your example will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! Without 'another: twice.dep', twice.dep is considered an intermediate and appropriately deleted (if created). With that line, it's no longer considered an intermediate. Why?

Comment: Because the definition of intermediate files is a file that "does not exist and **is not mentioned**".  By listing the file as a prerequisite, that counts as "mentioned" in the makefile.  It just has to be mentioned explicitly in _any_ rule (not recipe) to remove its eligibility for intermediate status.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rule

```
.INTERMEDIATE: %.dep
```

is not interpreted as a pattern rule (because it lacks a `%` on the left hand side),
and `%.dep` is not a file.

For example, try this Makefile:

```
foo: %.bar
    cat $+ > $@
```

Now create `a.bar` and `b.bar` and run `make foo`.

Comment: If that is the cause, then may I suggest getting all the `.dep` files into a variable (using something like `DEPS := $(SRCS:.c=.dep)` or whatever as appropriate for your needs) then `.INTERMEDIATE: $(DEPS)`?

Comment: Yes, I think something along those lines will be required.

Comment: @reinierpost I think you believe that .INTERMEDIATE is a file target. Instead, it is a "special target" (and definitely not a pattern rule).  The documentation is unclear whether patterns are permissible, but they certainly are for .PRECIOUS. In any case, .INTERMEDIATE with a pattern or with an explicit 'twice.dep', or no .INTERMEDIATE at all, all give the same result.

Comment: @JackKelly The posted Makefile is the simplest case I could muster that replicates the problem.  It is not the actual Makefile in which the problem was discovered (and which already uses the construct you suggest). The use of literal dependencies or variable dependencies is immaterial. (But keep the ideas coming!)

Comment: Well, I've gone through the GNU make 3.82 source code but I can't quickly figure out whether .INTERMEDIATE supports patterns as dependencies.