# Can you explicitly declare a mentioned file .INTERMEDIATE?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936044/5452773), MadScientist, the current maintainer of GNU Make says on explicitly declared .INTERMEDIATE targets:

> [a file] just has to be mentioned explicitly in any rule (not recipe) to remove its eligibility for intermediate status.

On the other hand, [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) says

> However, you can explicitly mark a file as intermediate by listing it as a prerequisite of the special target .INTERMEDIATE. This takes effect even if the file is mentioned explicitly in some other way.

Which is right or what did I get wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's a misunderstanding: both of the above statements are true, but the context you apply (*on explicitly declared .INTERMEDIATE targets*) is not correct; that statement was in response to a question asked in a comment to my answer, which was different than the original question.

With no special overrides, a target is eligible to be intermediate if it's completely inferred by make (not listed anywhere explicitly in the makefile but only discovered through implicit rule search).

If a target is listed as a target or prerequisite in a makefile, then it is not eligible to be intermediate by default.  The `.INTERMEDIATE` special form allows you to declare that a target that is mentioned to be intermediate even so.

To ensure a target is *not* intermediate, it's enough to simply mention it in the makefile as a target or prerequisite of some target, somewhere (doesn't have to be one that is actually built during that invocation of make).

To ensure a target *is* intermediate, it either should not be mentioned or else it should be declared a prerequisite of `.INTERMEDIATE`.

Comment: Can you point me to what the correct context would be? As far as I understood, both the question and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936044/5452773) contained an explicit .INTERMEDIATE target declaration (`.INTERMEDIATE: twice.dep`). The comment in question then just added (and removed again) another  statement. Are `.dep` files even considered as intermediate targets?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the text you quote is not from my answer, it's from a comment on my answer... and that comment is not related to the original question, it's answering the question posed in the other comment: _Without 'another: twice.dep', twice.dep is considered an intermediate and appropriately deleted (if created). With that line, it's no longer considered an intermediate. Why?_  My comment explains why adding `another: twice.dep` ensures that `twice.dep` is not considered intermediate.

Comment: Make doesn't know anything about `.dep` files.  It treats them just like any other file.  In fact, make has NO special class of targets that it inherently treats any different than any other class based on name, etc. (except for ones impacted by default implicit targets I guess).

Comment: That was my impression, too (I didn't know, though, if there were any other thing than default implicit targest). So if it's not implicitly considered intermediate, and `.INTERMEDIATE:` doesn't care whether it's mentioned somewhere, what's the matter with the other line, then? It doesn't seem to change anything in this case: `.INTERMEDIATE:` + other line: intermediate, `.INTERMEDIATE:` + no other line: intermediate, no `.INTERMEDIATE:` + other line: not intermediate, no `.INTERMEDIATE:` + no other line: not intermediate...

Comment: It's pretty simple so I'm not sure where the confusion is.  I've said multiple times: if the target is not mentioned in the makefile (but is found due to implicit rules) then it's intermediate.  If it is mentioned, it's not intermediate.  Separately from that, if the target is listed as a prerequisite of `.INTERMEDIATE`, then it's intermediate regardless of whether it's mentioned or not.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: If you want your target to be intermediate, then either never mention it or declare it `.INTERMEDIATE`; either one will do the job.  If you _don't_ want your target to be intermediate, do mention it _and_ don't declare it to be `.INTERMEDIATE`.

Comment: In your comment above your last clause is wrong: no `.INTERMEDIATE` + no other line means it _IS_ intermediate.

Comment: I think what makes it confusing is that there's no clear definition of "mentioning". So if I provide a rule with a file as target (in this example, twice.dep), does that count as mentioning or will the file be intermediate? If the former is the case, how could it be _implicitly_ intermediate; by having a pattern rule for it?

Comment: I;m not sure what's confusing; for example I said _If a target is listed as a target or prerequisite in a makefile, then it is not eligible to be intermediate by default._  This implies that "mentioning" means, using a specific file as either a target or a prerequisite.  It seems pretty clear to me.  So in your example yes, definitely that counts as "mentioning".  Intermediate files occur in situations where you have a rule: "foo.a : foo.b", then _two_ pattern rules: `%.b : %.c` and `%.c : %.d`.  `foo.c`  is never mentioned in the makefile, it's inferred: it's an _intermediate_ file.